# Accessing values from an array of objects in MustacheJS

Tags: javascript, mustache

How do I access values from an array of Objects in MustacheJS? For example using `{{foo[0].bar}}` does not result in a valid render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done with dot (`.`)

```
{{foo.0.bar}}
```